# require a file in a .rabl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

I'm using RABL for my API building in rails and I have this tiny function that I use a LOT in my .rabl files. Is there to put it in a .rabl or .rb file somewhere and `require` that file in all my .rabls ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you have access to your view helpers in RABL. Isn't it sufficient for what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: Well, actually I'm making calls to rabl functions inside (such as `node(:somelabel)`) which are not reachable from the helper. So I guess I can't use an helper, any other idea?!

Answer (score 0):

You can use helpers in your `rabl` templates. See [here](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl#template-scope) for more details.